# Internal Functions work but External Page Functions are ignored

Tags: php, javascript, function

So I am creating a website and in it I need to have a shopping cart. Now when I arrive to the checkout where the user has to input the details, the javascript won't work.

I need to have certain validations on each field such as every field being filled and letters only in Name, address having at LEAST 20 characters and so.

The problem is this, when I tried to do the function internally (inside the same page) it worked perfectly, when I tried to fetch it from another external file called validateForm.js, it just doesn't work at all.

this is for assignment purposes and one of the requirements is to have all the JS in a separate file.

This is part of the checkout.php (where the details are to be added)

**Part of Checkout.php**

```
<div class="overview">
        <h1> Please make sure that the order is correct before entering the details and proceeding for Checkout.</h1>

    </div>
</div>


    <div class="form">
        <form name="sendEmail" action="sendEmail.php" onsubmit="return checkEmpty()" method ="post">
            <table class="tablealign" id="tablecheckout">

            <th>Fill in All Details</th><th></th>
            <tr><td>Name:*</td>         <td><input type="text" name="name"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Surname:*</td>      <td><input type ="text" name="surname"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Address:*</td>      <td><input type ="text" name="address"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Town:*</td>         <td><input type ="text" name="town"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Telephone:*</td>        <td><input type ="text" name="Telephone"></td></tr>

            </table>

        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Confirm Checkout">  
        </form>
        </div>
```

Now the functions are found in the validateForm.js in which the functions are these:

**validateForm.js**

```
//To check that ALL characters are letters


function allLetters(input)  
    {   
        var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
        if(input.value.match(letters))  
        {  
            return true;  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            alert('Only LETTERS are allowed in the Name');  
            document.sendForm.email.focus();
            return false;  
        }  

    }  

//To check that ALL characters are numbers

function allNumbers(input)
    {

        var numbers = /^[0-9]+S/;
        if (input.value.match(numbers))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            alert ('Only Numbers are allowed in the Mobile Field');
            document.sendForm.mobile.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

// Check Validity of Email
function checkEmail()
{
        var x = document.forms["sendForm"]["email"].value;
        var atPosX= x.indexOf("@");
        var dotPosX = x.indexOf(".");

        if (atposX<1 || dotPosX < atPostX+2 || dotPosX+2 >= x.length)
        {
            alert("Please Provide a Valid E-Mail Address");
            document.sendForm.email.focus();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;    
        }
    }

// Check whether every field is filled
function checkEmpty()
{
    var name = document.forms["sendForm"]["name"].value;
    var surname = document.forms["sendForm"]["surname"].value;
    var address = document.forms["sendForm"]["address"].value;
    var town = document.forms["sendForm"]["town"].value;
    var telephone = document.forms["sendForm"]["telephone"].value;

        if (name == null || name == "" || surname== "" || surname == null || address == null || address == "" || telephone == null || telephone == "" || town == null || town == "")
        {
            alert ("ALL Fields are to be filled in");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
}

//Check that the Address is longer than 20 characters

function checkAddress()
{
    if (document.forms.sendForm.address.value.length < 20)
    {
        alert ('Address must be AT LEAST 20 characters long');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

in the **checkout.php** HEAD tag there is this:

```
<head> 
    <title> USA Women's Soccer Team Unofficial Website| Checkout PAGE   </title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML, JavaScript">
    <meta name="description" content="USWNT Unofficial Website News and Players Homepage News ">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="GeneralBackground.css">
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="validationForm.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
```

N.B. sendEmail.php is just a blank page for now as it has still not been developed, but what I'm baffled is that the Internal works but the functions in another file are totally ignored.

If you can give me some tips what could be the cause of this problem I would greatly appreciate

Comment: The only problem i see is that browser cannot find validateForm.js. Verify that it is actually there.

Comment: It is there, could it be because sendEmail.php is still a blank page?

Comment: add console.log() or alert into validateForm.js. Does it work? If no, browser cannot find the file. In Chrome/Firefox open page source and click on the `src="validationForm.js"`.

Comment: It's ignoring it completely... I just noticed... it;s not being read in Chrome.. it src="".. when it is in the same file as the all the php

Comment: if `validationForm.js` is in document root directory just add a slash `src="/validationForm.js"`